# Pagina web con poductos 3d

Tags: javascript, html, web, 3d

Estoy creando una pagina web que es una tienda de ripa y quiero que me muestre los productos en 3D pero el problema que tengo ahora mismo es que no veo el producto en 3D, sino que me sale la pantalla en negro.

He puesto 3 productos de ejemplo para ver si funcionaba pero se queda la pantalla en negro.

Lo he hecho con Three.js

Me pueden ayudar porfa. les dejo el codigo que tengo hecho.
gracias.

```js
// Crear una escena
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Crear una cámara
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 5;

// Crear un lienzo WebGL
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.getElementById('canvas-container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Variables para el modelo 3D
var selectedProduct = null;
var object3D = null;

// Manejador de eventos para seleccionar un producto
function selectProduct(event) {
  var selectedElement = event.target.closest('.product');
  if (selectedElement) {
    // Deseleccionar el producto anteriormente seleccionado
    if (selectedProduct) {
      selectedProduct.classList.remove('selected');
    }

    // Seleccionar el nuevo producto
    selectedProduct = selectedElement;
    selectedProduct.classList.add('selected');

    // Cargar el modelo 3D del producto seleccionado
    var modelUrl = selectedProduct.dataset.modelUrl;
    loadProduct3DModel(modelUrl);
  }
}

// Cargar el modelo 3D del producto seleccionado
function loadProduct3DModel(modelUrl) {
  // Limpiar la escena de modelos anteriores
  if (object3D !== null) {
    scene.remove(object3D);
  }

  // Cargar el modelo 3D utilizando Three.js
  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  loader.load(modelUrl, function(object) {
    // Escalar el modelo para ajustarlo adecuadamente en la escena
    object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
    object.position.set(0, 0, 0); // Ajustar la posición del modelo si es necesario
    object.rotation.set(0, 0, 0); // Ajustar la rotación del modelo si es necesario
    scene.add(object);
    object3D = object;

    // Llamar a la función de animación después de cargar el modelo 3D
    animate();
  });
}

// Funciones para controlar la cámara
function zoomIn() {
  camera.position.z -= 0.1;
}

function zoomOut() {
  camera.position.z += 0.1;
}

function rotateLeft() {
  if (object3D) {
    object3D.rotation.y += 0.1;
  }
}

function rotateRight() {
  if (object3D) {
    object3D.rotation.y -= 0.1;
  }
}

// Manejador de eventos para cambiar la textura del modelo 3D
function changeTexture(event) {
  var selectedTexture = event.target.closest('.texture-control');
  if (selectedTexture && object3D) {
    var textureUrl = selectedTexture.dataset.textureUrl;
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    textureLoader.load(textureUrl, function(texture) {
      object3D.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
          child.material.map = texture;
          child.material.needsUpdate = true; // Actualizar el material para reflejar la nueva textura
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

// Agregar el manejador de eventos al hacer clic en un producto
var productElements = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
Array.from(productElements).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', selectProduct);
});

// Agregar el manejador de eventos a los controles
document.getElementById('zoom-in').addEventListener('click', zoomIn);
document.getElementById('zoom-out').addEventListener('click', zoomOut);
document.getElementById('rotate-left').addEventListener('click', rotateLeft);
document.getElementById('rotate-right').addEventListener('click', rotateRight);

// Agregar el manejador de eventos al cambiar la textura
var textureControls = document.getElementsByClassName('texture-control');
Array.from(textureControls).forEach(function(control) {
  control.addEventListener('click', changeTexture);
});

// Animación de rotación
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (object3D !== null) {
    object3D.rotation.y += 0.01;
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Tienda de Ropa 3D</h1>

  <div id="canvas-container"></div>

  <div id="product-list">
    <div class="product" data-model-url="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/OBJ/T-Shirt-Man.obj">
      <img src="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/OBJ/personalizado.jpg" alt="Producto 1">
      <p>Producto 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-model-url="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/OBJ/T-Shirt-Man.obj">
      <img src="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/OBJ/personalizado.jpg" alt="Producto 2">
      <p>Producto 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-model-url="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/OBJ/T-Shirt-Man.obj">
      <img src="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/OBJ/personalizado.jpg" alt="Producto 3">
      <p>Producto 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="controls">
    <div class="control" id="zoom-in">Acercar</div>
    <div class="control" id="zoom-out">Alejar</div>
    <div class="control" id="rotate-left">Rotar Izquierda</div>
    <div class="control" id="rotate-right">Rotar Derecha</div>
  </div>

  <div id="texture-controls">
    <div class="texture-control" data-texture-url="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/Textures/">Textura 1</div>
    <div class="texture-control" data-texture-url="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/Textures/">Textura 2</div>
    <div class="texture-control" data-texture-url="http://localhost/API_clima/T-Shirt/Textures/">Textura 3</div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/110/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
```

---

Dejo tambien el codigo de javascript.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/110/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Crear una escena
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Crear una cámara
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 5;

    // Crear un lienzo WebGL
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.getElementById('canvas-container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Variables para el modelo 3D
    var selectedProduct = null;
    var object3D = null;

    // Manejador de eventos para seleccionar un producto
    function selectProduct(event) {
      var selectedElement = event.target.closest('.product');
      if (selectedElement) {
        // Deseleccionar el producto anteriormente seleccionado
        if (selectedProduct) {
          selectedProduct.classList.remove('selected');
        }

        // Seleccionar el nuevo producto
        selectedProduct = selectedElement;
        selectedProduct.classList.add('selected');

        // Cargar el modelo 3D del producto seleccionado
        var modelUrl = selectedProduct.dataset.modelUrl;
        loadProduct3DModel(modelUrl);
      }
    }

    // Cargar el modelo 3D del producto seleccionado
    function loadProduct3DModel(modelUrl) {
      // Limpiar la escena de modelos anteriores
      if (object3D !== null) {
        scene.remove(object3D);
      }

      // Cargar el modelo 3D utilizando Three.js
      var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      loader.load(modelUrl, function(object) {
        // Escalar el modelo para ajustarlo adecuadamente en la escena
        object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0); // Ajustar la posición del modelo si es necesario
        object.rotation.set(0, 0, 0); // Ajustar la rotación del modelo si es necesario
        scene.add(object);
        object3D = object;

        // Llamar a la función de animación después de cargar el modelo 3D
        animate();
      });
    }

    // Funciones para controlar la cámara
    function zoomIn() {
      camera.position.z -= 0.1;
    }

    function zoomOut() {
      camera.position.z += 0.1;
    }

    function rotateLeft() {
      if (object3D) {
        object3D.rotation.y += 0.1;
      }
    }

    function rotateRight() {
      if (object3D) {
        object3D.rotation.y -= 0.1;
      }
    }

    // Manejador de eventos para cambiar la textura del modelo 3D
    function changeTexture(event) {
      var selectedTexture = event.target.closest('.texture-control');
      if (selectedTexture && object3D) {
        var textureUrl = selectedTexture.dataset.textureUrl;
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        textureLoader.load(textureUrl, function(texture) {
          object3D.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              child.material.map = texture;
              child.material.needsUpdate = true; // Actualizar el material para reflejar la nueva textura
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }

    // Agregar el manejador de eventos al hacer clic en un producto
    var productElements = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
    Array.from(productElements).forEach(function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', selectProduct);
    });

    // Agregar el manejador de eventos a los controles
    document.getElementById('zoom-in').addEventListener('click', zoomIn);
    document.getElementById('zoom-out').addEventListener('click', zoomOut);
    document.getElementById('rotate-left').addEventListener('click', rotateLeft);
    document.getElementById('rotate-right').addEventListener('click', rotateRight);

    // Agregar el manejador de eventos al cambiar la textura
    var textureControls = document.getElementsByClassName('texture-control');
    Array.from(textureControls).forEach(function(control) {
      control.addEventListener('click', changeTexture);
    });

    // Animación de rotación
    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      if (object3D !== null) {
        object3D.rotation.y += 0.01;
      }

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar esta librería https://modelviewer.dev/